# Disable Screensaver (Black Screen) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, brightness, screensaver

**Background :**

I have an application which is running on top of Ubuntu 12.04. When I boot up the device, it will automatically open the application and running until power off the device.

**Problem :**

When the application is on `IDLE` state display is going to off mode (Black Screen). I need to disable that behaviour from the OS.

**What I have done So far :**

The `Brightness and Lock` as follows,

[image]

I run following command in the terminal also,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

But still my problem remain same. Any idea how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days I succeed by running following codes in terminal,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```

But in few articles I saw that we need do some extra works if those steps not working with your system as follows,

Add or edit `.xsession` file(which is located in your home directory) with following lines,

```
xset s 0 0
xset s off
```