# screen keeps black in ubuntu 13.10 when it must come out of sleep mode

Tags: screen, brightness, restart, lock

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on a completely new machine, was fresh installed. After a while, while not working on it, the screen turns black, when you try to work again, you can't exit the black screen, you are forced to restart the computer. I tried various settings and also changed the setting in "brightness and lock" for when the screen turns off when inactive to a longer time. What can I do to rectify? This isn't normal about Ubuntu, right? [image]

Answer (score 0):

try following code to disable the black screen as I mention in [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/379241/214930).

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0
```